# Maximum TCP connection duration generally or in java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection, timeout

Is there a maximum TCP connection duration or is it okey to keep such a TCP connection open for several days? (Of course with keep alive packets)

And especially: Is there such a connection duration limit in Java's TCP Socket and SocketServer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a maximum TCP connection duration

Not unless a router enforces one, but they do.

> or is it okey to keep such a TCP connection open for several days? (Of course with keep alive packets)

You can try. Good luck. It isn't likely to succeed, and you shouldn't rely on it.

> And especially: Is there such a connection duration limit in Java's TCP Socket and SocketServer?

No.